# running consecutive commands in bash

Tags: code-golf

Usually to run multiple commands consecutively one would do:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade # 35 characters
```

I can't help but feel there's a neat trick to running these with less keystrokes, and you golfers here love challenges :)

I've found a ton of answers around various SE Sites related to running arguments to different commands or commands in parallel, but nothing like what I'm after.

I've come to achieve what I want a couple of ways, but it's way longer and more difficult to type:

```
 x=('update' 'upgrade') && for i in ${x[*]}; do sudo apt $i; done
```

I quickly shortened this to:

```
for x in update upgrade; do sudo apt $x; done
```

then

```
for x in update upgrade;do sudo apt $x;done # 43 characters
```

Using `bash`, what is a golfed way of achieving the above? shortest line wins

(this is my first post to the group, please be kind if I've used the wrong tags) ;)

edit: as pointed out my own loops don't exactly do what is in the question due to the `&&` being conditional on the first command not having an error (I do know this). There's also the fact that my loops (and the original command line without the `-y` switch) still requires user input to complete. An oversight. Time for some more explicit instructions.

My original thought was to have something like:

```
echo update upgrade | sudo apt
```

with the objective of just running one after the other.

In the interests of trying to open this up to other languages, let's expand it thusly:

Objectives:

- run both commands
- require no more than one additional keystroke by the user
- can outsource this to other other languages/scripts*
- can be scripted if:

  - gracefully fails (error messages are ok, but it shouldn't try and execute anything else in error)
  - it's something commonly or "unobtrusively installable" in linux/ubuntu (I feel I may regret this line)
  - the script takes at least three arguments
  - 1. command to run
  - 2. argument 1
  - 3. argument 2
  - 4. argument n
  - or specified on the command line, (see next example)
  - in this second case, see the note below

    `./twice "sudo apt" update upgrade`

*I have it in mind that someone could construct a cute little binary/script from a `printf`, but the essence is, if it can be run from an executable script, all characters of the script EXCEPT the first line (the shebang) count.

If I've totally messed this up, feel free to close. Cheers

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site!  Generally we don't like language specific challenges here because they leave out people who don't golf in that language.  However I don't see a way to include other languages and its not against the rules so it should be fine.

Comment: I would also recommend clarifying exactly what you want out of solutions.  I assume you want to update and upgrade your packages based on the code provided but I would recommend explicitly outlining what you want from submissions.  Its nice to do this because golfing often involves going right up against the rules of the challenge and its better if these things are explicitly defined.

Comment: Note that your loops aren't equivalent to the original command. Because of `&&`, the second one will run only if the first didn't encounter an error.

Comment: I feel I've bitten off more than I can chew and messed up the whole essence of the original intent. Feel free to close this if that's the case.

Comment: @Dennis But that could easily be fixed by substituting `;`.

Comment: My personal recommendation is not to use the word "guys" when addressing a general readership. Research shows that "guys" is not a gender-neutral term, in terms of the images and defaults it evokes in readers' minds; and using gender-specific terms reinforces our unconscious biases against women in technical fields, and makes them feel even less welcome.

Comment: @GregMartin so, "Everyone" or "People"?

Comment: BTW, saving that to a file and saving to startup totally destroys the need of such command.

Comment: @GregMartin certainly not intended, edited none-the-less http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 40 bytes

```
for a in ${@:2};do eval "${1} ${a}";done
```

Usage: `./[filename] "[primary command]" [arguments]`

Ex. `./twice "sudo apt" update upgrade` (Assumes 'twice' as file name)

Was this what you wanted?

*Note: Please golf me further if it is possible, and correct me if I'm wrong. This was my first bash entry.*

Comment: I was just doing this. Ninja'd me well :D

Comment: I think you can replace `do` and `done` with braces

Comment: Hence `for a in ${@:2};{ $1 $a;}` suffices in `#!/bin/bash -e`

Answer (score 1):

### 24 bytes

Interactively, you can reduce this to 24 keystrokes (plus root password)

```
su
apt update
^dat^grad
```

An abstract script starts at 25 bytes +boilerplate:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
for x in ${@:2}
{
$1 $x
}
```

or at 29 bytes:

```
printf "$1 %s
" ${@:2}|sh -e
```

as in

```
e(){ printf "$1 %s\n" ${@:2}|sh -e;}
e "sudo apt" up{dat,grad}e
```

For concrete one-liners, the 32 bytes of

```
sudo sh -ec apt\ up{dat,grad}e\;
```

are only 1 byte shorter than

```
sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade
```

or 3 bytes shorter than

```
e(){ sudo apt up$1e;};e dat&&e grad
```

Comment: *facepalm* **why?**

Comment: the sh -ec "apt update;apt upgrade;" error exits (-e) on update error

Comment: No. That was not what I meant. nearly everyone (including betseg, one of the primary users on PPCG) is being confused of the question and just answer how to do the equivalent of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Sorry, but read the question again please.